# Parse binary data from CSV file - CertificateException

Tags: csv, certificate, x509, der

I try to parse certificate data from an big .csv file. The documentation says it is a X509 certificate stored in raw data encoded with base64.

So i tried to decode it and load the data with java using this code:

```
protected X509Certificate parseCert(byte [] bytes) {
    if (bytes != null) {
        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(org.apache.commons.net.util.Base64.decodeBase64(bytes));
        X509Certificate certificate = null;
        try {
            CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
            certificate = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(in);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return certificate;
    }

    System.out.println("Null value in bytes!");
    return null;
}
```

I always get a `CertificateException` saying "Empty Data". I don't know what i am doing wrong!

With a CSV reader the data looks good, or must I cut off \x3 ?

> ```
>  \x308202e23082024ba0......
>  \x30820224308201....
> ```

And:

> \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

May be someone can help?

Comment: *must i cut off \x3* - try cutting off the **\x**. The rest looks hex-encoded, though, not base64-encoded.

Comment: thx for your quick reply. Tried it resulting in a Parsing Exception: "Incomplete Data"

Comment: *"Incomplete Data"* - maybe it *is incomplete*. You might want to add the exact `bytes` byte array contents for a sample failure. And as mentioned the data looks hex-encoded, not base64. Have you tried hex-decoding?

Comment: Added a sample data set

Comment: Also hex ends up in java.security.cert.CertificateException: Could not parse certificate: java.io.IOException: Empty input tested in debug string is not empty

Comment: I think @mkl is right. Remove the `\x`; and then `HexDecode` it. The `HexDecode` will transform the remaining string from ASCII to binary. The binary is actually Distinguished Encoding Rules or DER (as opposed to Privacy Enhanced Mail or PEM). Its clearly *not* Base64 encoded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The certificate is not base64-encoded but hex-encoded.

Changing the code of the OP's `parseCert` method to

```
protected X509Certificate parseCert(byte[] bytes)
{
    if (bytes != null)
    {
        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(Hex.decode(bytes));
        X509Certificate certificate = null;
        try
        {
            CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
            certificate = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(in);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return certificate;
    }

    System.out.println("Null value in bytes!");
    return null;
}
```

(making use of the BouncyCastle hex decoder `org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Hex`, but any other should also do) results in successful parsing of the certificate in

```
@Test
public void test24542431() throws CertificateEncodingException, IOException
{
    String hexEncodedCert = "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";
    X509Certificate cert = parseCert(hexEncodedCert.getBytes());
    Files.write(FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("target/test-outputs", "24542431.crt"), cert.getEncoded());
}
```

which is not trusted here, though:

[image: Certificate dialog, not trustworthy]

Comment: Thx man i did not got rid of the \ char ;) i appreciate your help